# Iterate over 2 nested lists

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a weather app and need to go through 2 nested loops. For the `return` value I want to iterate over the first list, looking at the corresponding second list data. When the data in the second list matches the `bool`, I need to get data from the corresponding first list. Now I *think* that my code works... but would like to ask if this is a good way to do this. I am also not sure if this LINQ query will work in general, with even more nested lists. Here's my approach in LINQ:

```
public static async Task<string> UpdateWeather(string lat, string lon)
{
    WeatherObject weather = await WeatherAPI.GetWeatherAsync(lat, lon);

    var first = (from l in weather.list
                from w in l.weather
                where w.id == 800
                select l.city.name).First();

    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK, it is a LINQ query.But one more thing. Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`. `First()` will throw an exception if no matched element is found, but `FirstOrDefault()` will return the element or the default value.

You can also write in `LINQ Method syntax` if you prefer this.

```
public static async Task<string> UpdateWeather(string lat, string lon)
{
    WeatherObject weather = await WeatherAPI.GetWeatherAsync(lat, lon);

    var first = weather.list.Where(l => l.weather.Any(w => w.id == 800))
                            .Select(l => l.city.name)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

    return first;
}
```

Comment: `First` can work fine to define an implicit code contract. If you don't expect to get zero results then `First` is better than `FirstOrDefault`. Avoding exceptions shouldn't be a goal *per se*...

Comment: Agree with @MatíasFidemraizer - and it depends on the contract this method offers to the calling code.  Returning `.FirstOrDefault` will probably not prevent an exception, as it may just push the exception point up the stack, and cause the calling code to throw a null reference exception when it attempts to use the return value, which if anything, is less helpful than a "Sequence contains no elements" exception when trying to work out what happened.

Comment: @ChrisSimon So you can add an actual code contract after getting the `FirstOrDefault`: `Contract.Assert(weather != null);`. IMHO, this case should throw the exception. If you update a weather and there's no weather found by given lat/lng... something went wrong :D

Comment: Ultimately it depends on the story/use case/requirement this attempting to resolve - maybe the client (e.g. a UI) can handle there being no response? Maybe the UI should be able to handle multiple responses (see my answer for that case) - but in general, totally agree - an explicit contract that asserts the conditions that must be met is the clearest :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your query should work, and it should generally work with more nested lists following a similar structure.  As to if it is a good way to do this - it depends on the data structure and any data constraints.

For example, if two elements in `weather.list` have  an element in their nested `weather` list might have  the same id, then your code will only return the first one - which may not be correct.

e.g. in json:

```
[
  {
    city : {
      name : "Chicago"
    },
    weather : [
      {
        id = 799
      },
      {
        id = 800
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    city : {
      name : "New York"
    },
    weather : [
      {
        id = 800
      },
      {
        id = 801
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For this dataset, your code will return "Chicago", but "New York" also matches.  This may not be possible with the data API you are accessing, but given that there are no data constraints to ensure exclusivity of the nested lists, you might want to defensively check that there is only 0 or 1 elements in the returned list that match the expected criteria.

### Another suggestion

On another note, not strictly an answer to your question - if you *think* your code will work but aren't sure, write a unit test.  In this case, you'd wrap the call to WeatherAPI in a class that implements an interface you define.  Update your method to call the method on a reference to the interface.

For your real application, ensure that an instance of the wrapper/proxy class is set on the reference.

For the unit test, use a framework like [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) to create a mock implementation of the interface that returns a known set of data and use that instead.  You can then define a suite of unit tests that use mocks that return different data structures and ensure your code works under all expected structures.

This will be a lot easier if your class is not a static method as well, and if you can use dependency injection ([Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) or one of many others...) to manage injecting the appropriate implementation of the service.

Further explanations of unit testing, dependency injection and mocking will take more than I can write in this answer, but I recommend reading up on it - you'll never find yourself thinking "I *think* this code works" again!

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. I will definitely look into unit tests, which are a bit over my head right now.

Comment: No problems - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh694602.aspx might be a not bad place to start - it's just one specific way to do it with Visual Studio (there are many libraries to support it), but that page has some basic code samples to give you the idea of it.